# Advantages of particular "do while" macro in c?

Tags: c

I come across macros that are defined as follows:

```
#define CALL_FUNCS(x)
do {
  func1(x);
  func2(x);
  func3(x);
} while (0);
```

now, of course this will work but how is this any better than the below version ?

```
#define CALL_FUNCS(x)
{
  func1(x);
  func2(x);
  func3(x);
}
```

I think it is not about macro optimization. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: The C++ FAQ has [a good entry on this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.5)

Comment: Thanks Seth Carnegie, found the pointers: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do-While and if-else statements in C/C++ macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)

Answer (score 4):

The macro actually should not have the final ;. This is to get normal / more expected and helpful syntax errors around macro if something is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use the `do ...  while (0)` form in an `if-else` statement you will get an error:

```
if (bla) CALL_FUNCS();
else statement;
```

would be preprocessed as:

```
if (bla)
{
  func1(x);
  func2(x);
  func3(x);
};
else statement;
```

The semi-colon before the else statement is invalid.

Note (as pointed out by @arsenm) that you should not put the final `;` after the `do ...  while (0)` in the macro definition and you have to and use `\` after the lines in the definition:

```
#define CALL_FUNCS(x)  \
do {                   \
  func1(x);            \
  func2(x);            \
  func3(x);            \
} while (0)
```

Comment: @SethCarnegie, there are two trailing semicolons to consider. First, there is the incorrect extra semicolon at the end of the *definition* of the macro. But also look at how the macro is used; there is a semicolon in `CALL_FUNCS(x);` which won't disappear even if the second form is used.

Answer (score 3):

First, it should not have the trailing `;`. It should be:

```
#define CALL_FUNCS(x)    do { func1(x); func2(x); func3(x); } while (0)
```

Anyway, the reason is as follows. Consider

```
if(b)
     CALL_FUNCS(x);
else
     something_else(x);
```

This would expand to:

```
if(b)
     { func1(x); func2(x); func3(x); };
else
     something_else(x);
```

Now we still have a trailling `;` and will get this error message:

```
error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
```

Note, if you keep the `;` in the macro, then you will have *two* trailing `;`s!

Macro expansion should 'look' like something that expects a semicolon on the end. You're not going to type `CALL_FUNCS(x)`, you're going to call `CALL_FUNCS(x);`. You can rely on `do.. while(0)` to slurp up the semicolon, but `{ }` will not do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to force the user to add a `;` after the macro invocation.